# ServiceStack get ORMLite to use T4

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am evaluating T4 for ORMLite. Regardless of a couple glitches I made it working.  When I point the web.config to Northwind in MSSQL and run that from my SS web project the OrmLite.SP.cs automatically generates the following:

```
public class OrmLiteSPStatement
{
 ....
        try
        {
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
#pragma warning disable 618
            return reader.GetFirstColumn<T>();
#pragma warning restore 618
        }
        finally ...

        try
        {
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
#pragma warning disable 618
            return reader.GetScalar<T>();
#pragma warning restore 618
        }
        finally ...

        try
        {
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
#pragma warning disable 618
            return reader.GetFirstColumn<T>();
#pragma warning restore 618
        }
        finally ...

        try
        {
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
#pragma warning disable 618
            return reader.GetFirstColumnDistinct<T>();
#pragma warning restore 618
        }
        finally ...
```

They are all from the OrmLite.SP.cs auto-gen code in the OrmLiteSPStatement class...

```
   Error    1   No overload for method 'GetFirstColumn' takes 0 arguments 
   Error    2   No overload for method 'GetScalar' takes 0 arguments 
   Error    3   No overload for method 'GetFirstColumn' takes 0 arguments 
   Error    4   No overload for method 'GetFirstColumnDistinct' takes 0 arguments
```

When I move my mouse over to inspect the error, visual studio says:

`Cannot access internal method 'GetFirstColumn' here`

How do I fix it?

I am running VS2012, .Net 4.0, ServiceStack 3.9.38.0, SQL2008R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These T4 templates are still using the deprecated methods that were made internal last week.

[Raise an issue with the OrmLite project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/issues) (or pull-request) so we can keep track of the issue.

Comment: Oh :) thanks mythz. I have submited the issues to Github OrmLite project.